# User Input for 2D Array When Y Value is Greater than X Value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, user-input

My loop for the user input of a `2d array` looks like this:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
                System.out.println("Enter the value");
                int value = s.nextInt();
                inArray[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
```

The x and y values are imported from user and used to construct an `array` of size = new int[y][x]

It works fine when the x value is greater than the y value but when the other way around it doesn't output the right results

For example when I input a 5x5 `array` I get

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,1
2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,1,2
3,4,5,6,7
```

But if I try a 3x4 `array` I get this

```
1,2,34
5,6,78
9,1,23
```

The values 34, 78 and 23 are meant to be separate in its own column like this:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look @ below code:

```
public class Laptop {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] inArray = new int[10][10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.println("Enter the value");
                int value = scan.nextInt();
                inArray[i][j] = value;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                System.out.print(inArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The Output i am getting :

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: The error wasn't actually with my code, it was with my 2d array to csv code, thanks for helping me realizing that.